# How to change the default action, in the called app, per file type in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, vlc-media-player, file-association, double-click

I use Windows 10 and the default action when double-clicking on a MP3 file is to open it with VLC.  However, the file just gets added to the playlist, without playing it.  I'd like the default option to be "Play with VLC media player" (3rd in the menu).

This cannot be done in Win10's Start -> Settings -> Apps -> Default Apps, as there one can merely choose the app.

How can I do it?

[image]

Comment: This is a VLC pref, not a Windows pref. idk where it is in Win VLC, as the prefs structure is completely different to that on Mac, which is what I'm used to.

Answer (score 2):

In *Preferences*, *Playlist*, select *Auto start*.

[image: VLC select Auto start]

Comment: This does not work.  *Auto start* is already selected.